# Debian Systemd: Wifi network configuration waits at boot, connects after boot

Tags: debian, systemd, wifi, network-interface

This has been plaguing me since I updated to Debian 8. Everyone is probably familiar with the ["A start job is running for wait for network to be configured"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972215/a-start-job-is-running-for-wait-for-network-to-be-configured-ubuntu-server-17-1) message, and how prevalent it was for a while.

I have disabled the wait for network systemd service already, but that comes at a cost for other things, like network drives to not mount properly at startup, as well as waiting at boot.

I use a wifi interface, using wpa_supplicant, with the interface configured in `/etc/network/interfaces` file. Whats odd is that it doesn't connect at boot, but it does connect after the boot almost immediately, even when the wait for network service is disabled.

I have sprawled over journalctl to see why this happens, but I still can't seem to figure it out. Does anyone know why and how I can fix this in Debian 9?